# PHP Composer port change for installing packages

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, package-managers

I have two servers running. One on port 80 and other on 88. Now when i write command 
'php composer.phar install' and expects packages mentioned in composer.json to be installed, i got the msg Composer supports PHP > 5.3.2 and u have 5.3.1.

The server at :80 has 5.3.1 but
the server at :88 has 5.4.16

How can i say composer to use port :88. Even though I am htdocs of :88 and running composer from there.

Thanks

Comment: You force the composer with PHP composer.phar command where this PHP is your active 5.3.1 version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was when I ran the composer installer on windows, it selected the server with 5.3.*. I uninstalled it and re ran the setup, installed it, and selected the php.exe file of the other server. It works now. Thanks every body.

Answer (score 0):

The Composer command line executable does not use any "ports" of webservers, it uses the CLI version of PHP. If your two PHP versions on your server both provide a `php-cli` executable, but the wrong is used when you call `php -i`, you should redirect the path to point to the other one.

Comment: Yea you are right. CLI does not use ports for webserver, that was first what I was looking for. But in vain. Thank you!